# JBoss Drools Dependency does not load in maven

Tags: maven, jboss, drools

I have a very old project which I am trying to rebuild and the pom.xml has the following repository mentioned:

```
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-drools</id>
            <name>JBoss-Drools Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
```

The `mvn clean install` step however fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <WAR>: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project <WAR>:<SNAPSHOT>:
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.apache.xerces:xml-apis:jar:2.10.0,
org.apache.xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0, 
org.apache.xerces:resolver:jar:2.10.0, 
org.apache.xerces:serializer:jar:2.10.0, 
org.apache.xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1,
org.apache.commons.ssl:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.9:
Could not find artifact org.apache.xerces:xml-apis:jar:2.10.0
in jboss-drools (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/) ->
[Help 1]
```

I looked at the repository link mentioned, it does not have the jboss-drools dependencies anymore. Where can I find them ?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xerces/xml-apis/2.10.0 you can find this dependency in the soffid repository (http://download.soffid.com/maven/).